# Dagger 2 Both classes acting as Singletons, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, dagger-2

I am new at **dagger2** and practicing singletons but i am facing confusion i don't understand why is it happening.
Here is the logic, which is very straight forward: 
Two classes! Human and People. Human is **singleton** and people is simple class just *@inject constructor*.
When i make Human class singleton and use people in the @inject constructor of human class's parameter and try to print some log message and @Inject the human class in the main activity and call the human class function. It show both classes as a singleton. Here is some code.
**Human Class**

```
@Singleton
class Human @Inject constructor(
    private var people: People
){
    fun human(){
        Log.d(Tag,"Human-> $this || People-> $people ")
    } 
}
```

```
 //People Class
class People @Inject constructor()
```

```
//Component Interface
@Singleton
@Component
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var human: Human
    @Inject
    lateinit var humanTwo: Human

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val component = DaggerAppComponent.create()
        component.inject(this)

        human.human()
        humanTwo.human()
    }
}
```

Here is the output

```
2019-12-05 20:05:01.064 5831-5831/com.example.daggerinjection D/Human: Human-> com.example.daggerinjection.human.Human@49111bd || People-> com.example.daggerinjection.human.People@a5a53b2
```

```
2019-12-05 20:05:01.064 5831-5831/com.example.daggerinjection D/Human: Human-> com.example.daggerinjection.human.Human@49111bd || People-> com.example.daggerinjection.human.People@a5a53b2
```

See? I called Human class with different instances but human and people both acting as singletons, but actually people class is suppose to be different in second output.
But when i do this.

**Human Class**

```
@Singleton
class Human @Inject constructor()
```

```
//People Class
class People @Inject constructor(
    private var human: Human
) {
    fun person() {
        Log.d(Tag,"People -> $this || Human-> $human")
    }
}

//Interface is same as above nothing changed
```

**Main Activity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var people: People
    @Inject
    lateinit var peopleTwo: People

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val component = DaggerAppComponent.create()
        component.inject(this)
        people.person()
        peopleTwo.person()
    }
}
```

Output is, as it should be:

```
2019-12-05 20:11:53.292 6107-6107/com.example.daggerinjection D/Human: People -> com.example.daggerinjection.human.People@49111bd || Human-> com.example.daggerinjection.human.Human@a5a53b2
```

```
2019-12-05 20:11:53.293 6107-6107/com.example.daggerinjection D/Human: People -> com.example.daggerinjection.human.People@ba20f03 || Human-> com.example.daggerinjection.human.Human@a5a53b2
```

Why is that so?

Comment: For the 1st one, the output is correct. Since `Human` class is a singleton, it would be instantiated only once. And once `people` is assigned to it, why would it change unless you change it manually. So in that case, Dagger would never create another instance of `Human` for _human2_. It would just give you the already existing one.

Answer (score 0):

`Human` is a Singleton. Once an instance is created, Dagger would not create another instance. So `human2` is the same as `human1`. Since Dagger does not create another instance, `people` variable would be the same.

If you check `DaggerAppComponent` file in your generated code, you would see a null check for `Human` and create an instance only if it's null.

Comment: we can make any class as  a singleton? or there are some limitation? as i describe in @Rafael's answer which is this: ``ok, But if i say i wanna make Human as app level and Person/Face at Activity Level how would you do that? because when i am making human as app level and face/person at Activity scope it gives me error or can't use different scope as human class is using person/face class as its constructor parameter... but i have to make person class to app level and human class at activity level to make it work``

Answer (score 0):

Singleton means you will only have a single instance of this class. If you have a single `Human` you will always get the same `Human`with the same contents when you ask Dagger for it. You can't have a single `Human` and have him have two different `Faces` for example. So in your case `human1` and `human2` is the same `Human` you just changed the variables name, but it's still the same `Human`.

Comment: ok, But if i say i wanna make Human as app level and Person/Face at Activity Level how would you do that? because when i am making human as app level and face/person at Activity scope it gives me error or `can't use different` scope as human class is using person/face class as its constructor parameter... but i have to make person class to app level and human class at activity level to make it work

Comment: How about having a "HumanManager" that would be created at App Level and you would ask the "HumanManager" to "createNewHuman(new Hair(), new Face())" and that would return a new Human for you with the new Hair and new Face? This way you could create as many new Humans as you want and you would have a global manager to create new Humans from wherever you need in your App. If you want you could also hold the Humans you created in a List in the Manager so you can access Humans that have been created from different places.